# missing ingredients in banana bread

Tags: baking

I have my grandmothers handwritten recipe for banana bread. the paper tore and I lost some of the recipe. it calls for 1 1/2 cup sugar, 2 cups flour, 3/4 tsp baking soda, 1/2 cup of milk, 1 tsp vanilla, 3 mashed bananas. I lost the amount of salt, baking powder, shortening and eggs. can anyone tell me how much of each I need to make this recipe?????

Comment: I have made banana bread a gazillion times, always to recipes that were supposed to be extraordinary. The best (and I do mean BEST) recipe I have ever found was [America's Test Kitchen](http://www.americastestkitchen.com/recipes/6067-ultimate-banana-bread?incode=MASAZ00L0). It's a pay site, but it has a 14 day free trail. I'm sure your grandmother's recipe is special to you. The recipe I posted (sorry about the pay-wall) could be very special to your grandchildren.

Comment: @Jolenealaska To peak behind the paywall, the ingredients listed: 1 ¾ cups (8 3/4 ounces/248 grams) unbleached all-purpose flour; 1 teaspoon baking soda; ½ teaspoon table salt; 6 large very ripe bananas, (about 2 1/4 pounds), peeled; 8 tablespoons (1 stick) unsalted butter, melted and cooled slightly; 2 large eggs
¾ cup (5 1/4 ounces/149 grams) packed light brown sugar
1 teaspoon vanilla extract
½ cup walnuts, toasted and coarsely chopped (optional)
2 teaspoons granulated sugar

Answer (score 3):

That is a lot of sugar for that much flour. The salt and baking powder are likely to be one teaspoon each or 3/4 teaspoon each. It probably called for 1/2 cup shortening (consider butter or butter flavored Crisco, but that's just me), and 2 eggs. Give it a shot and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I agree -- that's about 50% more sugar than the sweetest banana bread I've ever made!

Answer (score 2):

My grandmother's recipe calls for the following (of the ingredients you asked):

1/2 C canola oil
1   tsp baking soda
1/2 tsp salt
1   egg

I agree with Jolenealaska; that's too much sugar.  Also maybe a bit much flour, but you might be making a loaf which rises to the top of the pan.

I prefer oil in this case.  It makes the loaf very moist.  I almost never use shortening.  I prefer butter or oil.